# Is there a Regex to get 5th occurence in a following string?

Tags: sql, regex, match, string-matching, vertica

I have a following string (well, UTM actually):

```
bla-ble-blo-bli-this-bad-blau-bleu
bla-ble-blo-bli-this_good-blau-bleu
```

5th position in UTM is called "Subject", and currently since I am using SQL to do any sort of transformations, I am using a very simple set of rules and some look-up table as I am splitting string on "`-`", but as you see, it fails on "this-bad" as it has a "`-`", but it works as expected on "`this_good`".

Is there a regex to get 5th occurence of this "Subject" part? I tried following regex, but I really don't know how to set it find only 5th occurence. The regex in question: `\w+(?=-[^-]*$)`.

Thank you!

Comment: `this-bad` broke the patterns, which is the issue `-` in pattern recognition doesn't work. could `this-bad` also appear in 1st, 2nd....and 6th? or only 5th?

Comment: Hi @JHH, it is possible for it to appear only in 5th place, not in 4th or 6th or any other. Unfortunately, yes, I am aware it breaks the pattern.

Comment: Are there always 7 parts? Also, please add the tag of the database you are using.

Comment: Hi @Bohemian, I've updated the tag with the RDBMS we are using. Also, there are always more than 5 dashes ("-"), but the important thing is, this pattern-breaking string is always in 5th place.

Comment: But is there at most 7 parts in the input, even if the 5th part may contain a dash?

Comment: Ah sorry @Bohemian, I wasn't clear enough. I was using logic 1 dash ("-") = 1 part, therefore you can have more than 5 parts, at most I found was 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the tail and head, leaving the 5th part:

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace('bla-ble-blo-bli-this-bad-blau-bleu', '(-[^-]+){2}$', ''), '([^-]+-){4}', '')
```

See [live demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4WWmZ2NNLQ2wjg3Wam35Ce/0).

Comment: Does the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Hm, seems like I have spoken too soon. For example, if you take a look at following demo, it does not work: [link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4WWmZ2NNLQ2wjg3Wam35Ce/0)

Comment: @G0000000se The link you posted is *my* link. You need to click "Update" if you want to make a new test. Or just message here with the input that doesn't work and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: Oh, my bad. You can see it here in that case (an actual "live" example): [expected result](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4WWmZ2NNLQ2wjg3Wam35Ce/2). And this one gives [bad result](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4WWmZ2NNLQ2wjg3Wam35Ce/3). In the second example, I would need to have "Superapp" and "dis" in two seperate columns. That is why it is so hard to actually come up with a pattern.

Comment: @G0000000se how does one distinguish `dis-bet-ret-int-Supercard-CashBack-dis-all` from being an 8-term string with 5th term `Supercard` from a 7-term string with `Supercard-CashBack` as the 5th term?